# 'int' object has no attribute 'ljust'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        text = int(raw_input('New data:'))
        print("Now place your tag to write")

        reader.write(text)
        print("Written")
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

After running I have this error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ljust'

Comment: Please correctly format your code before you post.

Comment: The `write` method most likely requires a `str` or `bytes` object, not an `int`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please include the full traceback of the error. It's likely the `reader.write` method needs a `str` input. consider wraping `text` in `str()`

Comment: Look at the [source code](https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/blob/master/SimpleMFRC522.py) and you'll see @Jaba is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `int()` conversion at the beginning:

```
text = raw_input('New data:')
```

... Because `write()` doesn't seem to support an `int` as parameter:

```
reader.write(text) # here was the problem
```

Comment: Ok , but How can I write a cost reduction program?

Comment: That's not what you wrote in the question. Please post it as a separate question, explaining in detail your problem, including all the code you've written so far, pointing the part where you're having trouble. And don't forget to include sample input and the expected output.

Comment: well , how I can write int number in this program?

Comment: Convert it with `int()` where you need as `int`, but not when passing the value to `write()`, which expects a `str`

Comment: Is it possible to take an example?

Comment: I can't, you have to provide more information, there is no way for me to know what you want to do, only you know your own code and what you need. My suggestion would be, post another question and explain what's your problem.